# UITableViewCell not updating even cellForRowAtIndex is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to display data from the server in a UITableViewCell. All the delegate methods are being called but the cells are not updating.

See my code below.

```
if(userSessionData !=nil) {
    NSString * cid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userSessionData 
    objectForKey:@"cid"]];
    NSString * sessionid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", 
    [userSessionData objectForKey:@"sessionid"]];

        NSMutableArray * inputArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [inputArray addObject:@"getAmcList"];
        [inputArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@searchscheme_option/%@/%@/%@/%@/%@",mfSharedManager.baseUrl,[mfSharedManager encodeStringTo64:assetType],[mfSharedManager encodeStringTo64:catagory],[mfSharedManager encodeStringTo64:amc],[mfSharedManager encodeStringTo64:cid],[mfSharedManager encodeStringTo64:sessionid]]];
        [mfSharedManager inputRequestMethod:inputArray withCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *dict) {
            self.responseDataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:dict];
            NSLog(@"%@",self.responseDataDictionary);
           [self callMethod];
    //                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//                    [self.equityTableView reloadData];
//                });
        }];

}
```

call method:

```
-(void)callMethod  {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//    self.equityTableView.delegate=self;
//    self.equityTableView.dataSource=self;
    [self.equityTableView reloadData];
});
 }
```

I am calling delegate methods `self.equityTableView.delegate=self;` and `self.equityTableView.dataSource=self` in `viewDidLoad`.

For testing i have kept `NSLog` in `cellForRowAtIndex`. Data is printing in log correctly, but the UI is not updating.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: show your view did load and tableview datasource and delegate methods.

Comment: You said you do `tableview.delegate=self;` and `tableview.dataSource=self`. But your var is named `equityTableView`, is that a typo? Also, in `callMethod` is `self.equityTableView` nil (if it's not a typo, that's what I guess the issue is)

Comment: just mentioned self.equityTableView as tableview. But in code i mentioned as self.equityTableView

Comment: @dreamBegin  self.equityTableView.delegate=self; self.equityTableView.dataSource=self;

Comment: what count you're returning in numberofrows ?

Comment: @SandeepMaganti : Can you please add your tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath code here ? so that i can check the exact issue

Comment: @SandipPatel-SM itextpad.com/hCBl5gLeR3

Comment: copy and paste that link you can find my code.

Comment: what was the count in  NSLog(@"%lu",[[[self.responseDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"Table"] count]);

Comment: If count returns properly, then plese check have you connected IBOutlet variables to custom cell EquityTableViewCell ?

Comment: Also in CellForRowAtIndexPath writing code which is iteratively goes to access inner dictioary value, use as below:  NSDictionary *dict = [[[[self.responseDataDictionary objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"Table"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; [dict objectForKey:@"S_NAME"]];  it helps to make code simplest. Now just print dict desctiption. does it getting correct value as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Please set delegate and datasource from Storyboard/XIB and set @interface TableVC:UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource > and check.

Comment: Tried. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @SandeepMaganti please show your tableview datasource and delegate methods

Comment: This is not mandatory to set data source and delegate to set from Storyboard/XIB.

Comment: Can you please share your faulty code project so that i can debug it and help you to identify exact issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your two delegate methods as mentioned below:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

- Does it returning expected values? If not then due to this it might not update your tableview. If everything ok then share your cellForRowAtIndexPath method code.